# How to store a large (10 digits) integer?

Tags: java

Which Java data type would be able to store a big numerical value, like 9999999999?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your concrete example could be stored in `long` (or `java.lang.Long` if this is necessary).

If at any point you need bigger numbers, you can try 
[`java.math.BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (if integer), or [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) (if decimal)

Comment: These classes are very slow, and should only be used if you really need a lot of digits.  10 digits can easily be stored in a "long."  However, should you need 50 to 5000 digits, these two classes are the best way to do it.

Comment: quite correct.. I instinctively assumed that he has tried the obvious, and didn't succeed. Edited my answer so that it's correct.

Answer (score 35):

In addition to all the other answers I'd like to note that if you want to write that number as a literal in your Java code, you'll need to append a `L` or `l` to tell the compiler that it's a `long` constant:

```
long l1 = 9999999999;  // this won't compile
long l2 = 9999999999L; // this will work
```

Comment: The suffix 'L' most gentlemen are missing

Comment: @CodeWorld: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 34):

You can store this in a `long`. A `long` can store a value from `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`.

Comment: To be clear, at least 18 digits. Same for long and Long.

Answer (score 8):

A primitive long or its [java.lang.Long](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) wrapper can also store ten digits.

Comment: +1 A long can store 18-19 digits with absolute precision. Unless the OP indicates that they need more than this, a long is a far better choice than BigInteger.

Comment: Long is better than BigInteger upto 18 digits. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 6):

Use BigInt datatype with its implicit operations. The plus point for it is it will not give answers in exponential representation. It will give full length result

Here is an example of addition

```
      BigInteger big1 = new BigInteger("1234567856656567242177779");
      BigInteger big2 = new BigInteger("12345565678566567131275737372777569");
      BigInteger bigSum = big1.add(big2);
      System.out.println(bigSum );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. if you found any same question anywhere then mark that question as a duplicate instead of giving same solution again. or you can give a link of your answer posted earlier before.

Answer (score 3):

you can use long or double.

Comment: A double? If the OP's example of `9999999999` is indicative, then there's no need to introduce floating-point imprecision for an integral number.

Comment: yup ben your right but was just showing him we can use these things too. It really depends on your business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could store by creating an object that hold a string value number to store in an array list.
by example: `BigInt objt = new BigInt("999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999");`

objt is created by the constructor of BigInt class. Inside the class look like.

```
BigInt{

ArrayList<Integer> myNumber = new ArrayList <Integer>();        

public BigInt(){}

public BigInt(String number){ for(int i; i<number.length; i++){ myNumber.add(number.indexOf(i)); } }

}
```

Comment: This is all completely irrelevant. He didn't ask about arrays or lists or numbers with 52 decimal digits. It doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper class [java.lang.Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) can store 10 digit easily.

```
   Long phoneNumber = 1234567890;
```

It can store more than that also.

**Documentation:**

```
public final class Long extends Number implements Comparable<Long> {
    /**
     * A constant holding the minimum value a {@code long} can
     * have, -2<sup>63</sup>.
     */
    @Native public static final long MIN_VALUE = 0x8000000000000000L;

    /**
     * A constant holding the maximum value a {@code long} can
     * have, 2<sup>63</sup>-1.
     */
    @Native public static final long MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffffffffffffL;
}
```

This means it can store values of range *9,223,372,036,854,775,807* to *-9,223,372,036,854,775,808*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take user input then you should take that as string, then convert that into long.

```
//Take user input using Scanner class

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = sc.next();

//Convert that to long

long num = Long.parseLong(str);

System.out.println(num); // This is not a string anymore
```